# Tomcat Application to WCF Service with Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: java, wcf, tomcat, iis, ssl

I have a Java application running on Tomcat and the application needs to consume a WCF service that requires client certificate authentication . I have the keystores and truststores configured on the client side and I have confirmed that the request is getting sent to IIS, however I'm getting an "unauthorized" error message from IIS logs. I'm wondering if there is any specific Tomcat configuration required in order to allow sending a client certificate from the client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the application code that is calling the WCF service, right?  In that case, I don't think Tomcat configuration is what you need - Tomcat's SSL configuration is about what SSL authentication happens when browsers and other web clients connect to the Tomcat server and its applications, not about what happens when the applications are themselves clients to other network services.  Rather, the application code calling the service needs to use an SSLContext created with the proper keystore, which will need to hold both the private key and certificate presented to the server for client authentication, and the certificates needed to authenticate the certificate presented by the WCF service.

Comment: Thanks Warren! I will look into my application code and post a separate thread if needed.

Comment: Added new thread related to my application code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972656/axis2-sslcontext-with-client-stubs